# Copy/Move selected taxonomy terms to another taxonomy for posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've been searching for about 2 hours now on a solution of copying/moving *selected* taxonomy values for each posts to another. Here's the situation.

I'm working on a site that has a post type of `articles` and I'm moving them back to the innate `post` post type. Within the `articles`, I've had a taxonomy that was for the categories and I've successfully moved over the terms to the default categories taxonomy for the `post` type.

Now, I'm ready to bulk convert the posts (`articles` -> `post`) which isn't a problem. But I need to have the selected terms that were checked in the old category taxonomy also checked/marked in the new one.

Is there any way to achieve this in a bulk fashion. I don't want my clients to have to go through every individual post and remark their category terms.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want a SQL query for achieving this?

Comment: @ManojKumar - Sure, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This will get all posts with $old_tax, copy the terms from $old_tax to $new_tax, and then set the $new_tax terms for those posts.

```
<?php
    function convert_tax($old_tax, $new_tax) {
        $pages = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $old_tax,
                    'operator' => 'EXISTS'
                )
            )
        ));

        foreach($pages as $post) {
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $old_tax );
            $term = array();

            foreach( $terms as $t ) {
                if( get_term_by( 'name', $t->name, $new_tax ) == false ) {
                    wp_insert_term( $t->name, $new_tax, $args = array() );
                    wp_set_post_terms($post->ID, array(intval($t->ID)), $new_tax ); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    convert_tax('policy_area', 'topic')

?>
```

Comment: For custom post types use wp_set_object_terms and not wp_set_post_terms.

Comment: And for custom posts the function needs to be in an init action I think after the custom post type taxonomy is created. This and my comment above was why I have spent several hours with wp_set_post_terms or wp_set_object_terms not working!

Answer (score 0):

as long as the slugs from your articles taxonomy map exactly to the slugs in your default category you should be able to do something like this for each article:

```
        $article_cats = wp_get_object_terms( $article_id, 'article-category' );
        $new_cats = array();
        foreach( $article_cats AS $t ) {
            $new_cats[] = $t->slug;
        }
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_cats, 'categories' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined and refined the previous solutions a bit to account for all post statuses (like pending and draft posts for example).

I also made sure to insert the new terms correctly, even if the name and slug are different (encountered something like "Get posts" - "get-pasts" because of a typo in a project).

It also works for custom post types.

```
function convert_tax($post_type, $old_tax, $new_tax) {
    $pages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        // Get all post statuses
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $old_tax,
                'operator' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        )
    ));

    foreach($pages as $post) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $old_tax );
        $new_terms = array();

        foreach( $terms as $t ) {
            $new_terms[] = $t->slug;
            
            if( get_term_by( 'slug', $t->slug, $new_tax ) == false ) {
                // Clones the terms into the new taxonomy
                // Added slug parameter to account for name and slug being different
                wp_insert_term( $t->name, $new_tax, $args = array('slug' => $t->slug) );
            }
        }
        
        // Re-sets previously set terms
        wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $new_terms, $new_tax );
    }
}

convert_tax('company', 'keywords', 'topics');
```